# Send Chatter Notification every 30 days until field is completed

Tags: lightning, process-builder, chatter

I am trying to use Process Builder to send a chatter notification every 30 days until field is completed. The record being created starts the process and there is a required date field that is filled out. The notification will go to the record owner. I need to send this chatter notification every 30 days until another field is completed.

What is the best way to get this notification sent every 30 days?

Comment: Why not use scheduled actions https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_limits_scheduled.htm&type=5